# How to check given tea leaf session id in dynatrace

Tags: dynatrace, tealeaf

have one tea-leaf session id,which is generated by some website against some logs,need to check this session id in dyntrace
please let me know what is the procedure to integrate and check the tea-leaf session id in dynatrace.

**Requirement:**

- Need to get some key value pair from dynatrace embedded logs
- Need to check the behavior of web page
- need to check the URL redirection captured through dynatrace

**Already Checked and Effort made**

- Checked the dashboard and search the tealeaf session id in search
  box-failed
- view tealeaf session board,there is no search box or parameter input
  box except *filter* to check session id
- checked user session,again there is no option to search any session
  id
- checked the existing dashboard for other integrations as well in
  dynatrace but nothing seems to be possibly work out for me

*Please suggest if there is any error or new way to integrate tealeaf or is there any option to search the tealeaf session id in dynatrace*

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how tealeaf saves it's session ID you could use it as a session tag or request parameter in Dynatrace to identify the session.